# Touch a Home Screen to alert a Message in android?

Tags: android, homescreen

When we have a Touch/Select a Home Screen to alert a Toast/Message (Message is 'Home Screen').

Testing/Learning Purpose Only. Guide Me.

Is it Possible?

Your answers and comments all are valuable me.

Guide Me, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this snippet to your code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    keyCode=KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Home key pressed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```